# Using a given number as a key, can I represent the value of 5 numbers as lower values?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

So given that there are 5 arbitrary numbers within a range of 0 - 99:

`34, 67, 23, 90, 87`

And a key, let's also say this has to be within the range of 0 - 99 also:

`60`

Using `60` as a key, is there any way we can represent the 5 original numbers as numbers that are all under `20`? Can this be done in such a way where we can get back to the 5 original numbers using the key while ideally maintaining the order of the numbers also?

Comment: Are the five initial numbers ordered, or can they be given back in any order?  Are duplicates of the five original numbers allowed?  (Unordered response and allowing duplicates seems to be indicated by the language of the question.)

Comment: I shall update the question to clarify - but ideally the order should remain, yes. Duplicates are also allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $100^5$ ways to choose five numbers in the range $[0,99]$ with replacement and with order.  So there are $10^{10}$ distinct correct answer that must be represented by your key and small numbers.

There are $100 \cdot 20^5 = 32 \times 10^7$ choices of key and small numbers.  You cannot represent $10^{10}$ needed answers with only $3.2\times 10^8$ possible answers.  So, no, this cannot be done.

Comment: OP specified that duplicates are allowed, so this is the answer that matches the question.  I did not allow duplicates, but that does not change the computation significantly.

Comment: @RossMillikan : Yes and no.  While ${10}^{10}$ and $9 \times 10^9$are quite similar ($\sim 10\%$ error), $3.2 \times 10^7$ and $1.86 \times 10^6$ are substantially less so ($\sim 2000\%$ error).

Answer (score 0):

There are $\frac {100!}{95!}=9,034,502,400$ ordered sets of five numbers that you can try to represent.  There are only $100 \cdot \frac {20!}{15!}=186,048,000$ ordered sets of five numbers under $20$ plus a key, so you don't have enough choices.

Comment: Note: duplicates are allowed.